# Passport session is getting invalidated

Tags: node.js, express, axios, passport.js, passport-local

After using localstrategy from passport once user is logged in when I am firing a xhr get request using axios it seems

`req.isAuthenticated()` returns false also `req.user` returns undefined.

I am using vueJs in the frontend. Can anyone help in this regard.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I found the answer. As I was using { resave: true } config in the express.session it was requiring me to save the session manually by req.session.save(). Now I have changed the resave config to false. Works fine now.